is it possible to take over tbe default delete handler in windows?
Like the copy handler when different software like teracopy takes over but for deleting stuff like I want byenow to kick in when I press delete,  not Microsoft delete trash box.

It's possible to take over the Delete key in Explorer,
by using a keyboard mapper like the free
AutoHotkey V1.
The following example script will map
Del in Explorer to your script:
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
Del::Msgbox, you pressed delete

However, you then need to find the selected file(s)/folder(s) and handle
all of them.
This article shows how to get the selected files:
Get paths of selected items in an explorer window.

That kinda defeats the purpose. Would thus script automatically delete what is selected?

AHK blocks the native function of the Del key, so it never reaches Explorer. The script can then do it your way.

If there is a way to hook that script with byenow so it deos the deleting instead, I'll be happy with that.

What's "byenow" ?

A program that deletes files much faster then windows. https://iobureau.com/byenow/

Windows delete is slow because of the Recycle Bin (which saved me a few times). You could delete much faster with permanent delete (Shift+Del), or you could Disable the Recycle Bin. I would really advise to stay with the slow Windows delete - at least you could undo wrong deletes.

Windows delete is slow because it's Windows, how do other programs do it faster?

They don't really : There is no other way to delete a file/folder than by using Windows API, so all products must use the same API. The only real difference is if the delete is permanent or to the Recycle Bin. Multi-threaded deletes might give some improvement, but not anything sensational.

sure, but other products do the job faster, I don't know how, I just know it is a fact.
